# Descriptive analyses (counts/proportions) in a data frame

Tags: r

I have this dataset where I am supposed to find a descriptive analysis out of it. The structure of the dataset is...

```
pasta<-read.csv("_eba2c079135882131db3690701bc9c97_PASTAPURCHASE_EDITED.csv")
```

More specifically, I want to know the following: How many households live in area 2, earn more than 20k, and have purchased more than 30 units of pasta over the whole time period?

```
data.frame':    40000 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ HHID  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TIME  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ PASTA : num  0.939 2.561 0.901 1.917 1.549 ...
 $ EXPOS : int  1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ AGE   : num  61.7 61.7 61.7 61.7 61.7 ...
 $ INCOME: num  25187 25187 25187 25187 25187 ...
 $ AREA  : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

and the head of the dataset is...

```
  HHID TIME     PASTA EXPOS      AGE  INCOME AREA
1    1    1 0.9394443     1 61.71076 25186.8    3
2    1    2 2.5609686     2 61.71076 25186.8    3
3    1    3 0.9011233     0 61.71076 25186.8    3
4    1    4 1.9165300     1 61.71076 25186.8    3
5    1    5 1.5487510     0 61.71076 25186.8    3
6    1    6 2.1694050     0 61.71076 25186.8    3
```

HHID is household id, PASTA is the amount of pasta purchased, expos is exposure and area is the area in which the household belongs to.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Currently, your question lacks focus. Try out some descriptive analyses and when you get stuck come back with concrete questions regarding your code

Comment: It's also better to provide a more general title like "how to do descriptive analyses based on subset of data" or things like that, because currently your title is more of an explanation of your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the rows for those `HHID` where the conditions match :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- pasta %>%
            group_by(HHID) %>%
            filter(any(AREA == 2 &  INCOME > 20000 & sum(PASTA) > 30))
```

Now to count number of household you can use

```
n_distinct(result$HHID)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't define the columns so I'm doing some assumptions but that should do the trick:

```
library(data.table)

pasta_house <-
  fread("HHID TIME     PASTA EXPOS      AGE  INCOME AREA
    1    1 0.9394443     1 61.71076 25186.8    3
    1    2 2.5609686     2 61.71076 25186.8    3
    1    3 0.9011233     0 61.71076 25186.8    3
    2    4 1.9165300     1 61.71076 25186.8    3
    1    5 1.5487510     0 61.71076 25186.8    3
    1    6 2.1694050     0 61.71076 25186.8    3")

pasta_house[AREA == 2 &  INCOME > 20000, .(HHID, pasta_sum = sum(PASTA)), by = HHID][pasta_sum > 30, .N]
```